# How to increase kaplan-Meier Survival Plots in sas resolution

Tags: graph, sas, resolution, survival-analysis

I want to increase the kaplan-Meier Survival Plot resolution using sas, but I am getting an error and I am not getting it. The error message displayed in the log
is:

> ERROR: No body file. HTML output will not be created.

The syntax I used is:

```
ods graphics on;
ods trace output;
ods html style=htmlbluecml image_dpi=300;
proc lifetest data=TMD_migraine  plots=survival(cb=HW failure test atrisk(maxlen=13)) 
notable;
time migraine_mo* migraine(0);
strata group / order=internal;
format group tonsillfmt.;
run;
ods html close;
ods trace off;
```

Please tell me how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying an HTML file output location that you can write to, such as the WORK directory:

`ods html file="%sysfunc(getoption(work))/myoutput.html";`

Sometimes the default location is not a place you have write access to.

You can increase the physical dimensions of the graph with the `width=` and `height=` options. For example, if you wanted to change the output to be 1920x1080, specify `width=1920px height=1080px`.